# How to prevent cursor from getting stuck in corner in Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, cursor

I have a dual monitor setup.
In previous versions of Mac OS, when I move the cursor from the left monitor to the right, it moves without any problem, regardless of how high or low on the screen the cursor is.

Ever since I installed Catalina, if the cursor is within an inch of the top or bottom of the screen, it won't move on to my other monitor. The cursor seems to move between monitors only if it is NOT in the top inch or bottom inch of the screen. Clearly this is an intentional "FEATURE" that was added in El Capitan

This is really annoying behavior. Is there some way I can revert it back to the behavior in Mavericks, El Captian, High Sierra (basically every version of Mac OS before this?)

I've tried looking in System preferences but can't find a setting for this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Its the most dumb thing.

You go to System Preferences -> Display -> Arrangement. Make sure both monitors are "in line" with each other".

XD